# can someone fix this code for google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

so i found this code that lets you upload a file from a direct link to google drive using google colab. but i have to edit the code each time i want to add a url to upload to google drive.

can anyone fix the code so that i can enter the url as a form instead of editing the code and maybe so that i can use the form to manually name the file. or auto naming would be fine. like "1.mp4" "2.mp4" and so on.

this is the code

```
import requests
file_url = "http://1.droppdf.com/files/5iHzx/automate-the-boring-stuff-with-python-2015-.pdf"

r = requests.get(file_url, stream = True)

with open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/python.pdf", "wb") as file:
  for block in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024):
    if block:
      file.write(block)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the file URL a form parameter by adding `#@param string` to the line:

```
file_url = "http://1.droppdf.com/files/5iHzx/automate-the-boring-stuff-with-python-2015-.pdf" #@param string
```

Comment: ah thank. what about manualy naming the file using a form or auto naming the file?